# MVC: pass parameter to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

MVC newbie question:

I'm picking up a URL of the form `go/{mainnav}/{subnav}`, which I've successfully routed to the `GoController` class, method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string mainnav, string subnav) {
  return View();
}
```

So far, so good.  But now I want the view to return different HTML, depending on the values of mainnav or subnav.  Specifically, inside a javascript block, I want to include the line:

```
myobj.mainnav = [value of mainnav parameter];
```

and, *only if subnav is not null or empty*:

```
myobj.subnav = [value of subnav parameter];
```

How do you pass those parameters to an aspx page that doesn't have a codebehind?

Comment: @dot.net : You want to know the solution in aspx page or mvc1 or mvc2 or mvc3 or mvc4 ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You use a `ViewModel` class to transfer the data:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public string MainNav { get; set; }
    public string SubNav { get; set; }

    public IndexViewModel(string mainnav, string subnav)
    {
        this.MainNav = mainnav;
        this.SubNav = subnav;
    }
}
```

Your action method then comes out

```
public ActionResult Index(string mainnav, string subnav)
{
    return View(new IndexViewModel(mainnav, subnav));
}
```

This means your view has to be strongly typed:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<YourNameSpace.IndexViewModel>" %>
```

In your view, you output the data like so:

```
myobj.mainnav = <%: Model.MainNav %>;
```

An alternative solution if you use MVC3, would be to use the dynamic `ViewBag`:

```
public ActionResult Index(string mainnav, string subnav)
{
    ViewBag.MainNav = mainnav;
    ViewBag.SubNav = subnav;
    return View();
}
```

which would be accessed in the page as so:

```
myobj.mainnav = <%: ViewBag.MainNav %>;
```

However, I would recommend that you read up on [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_Javascript) and see if you can improve your design to avoid this specific problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using MVC3 I would suggest passing the values into the `ViewBag`.

```
ViewBag.MainNav = "xxxx";
ViewBag.SubNav = null;
```

then on your view page, where you define the JavaScript and add the value.

if you dont have MVC 3 if you use `ViewData["MainNav"]`), to store your value has the same effect.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try accessing parameters from Request in your view?

i.e.

```
Request.Params["mainnav"]
```

or

```
Request.Params["subnav"]
```

Works in MVC

Comment: Just because you can do this, doesn't mean you should. It's the Controller's responsibility to interrogate the request and gather data to pass to the View.  The Controller should make the decision about where to source that data. Remember your SOLID principles people.

Answer (score 1):

i'm using following approach:

ViewModel.class:

```
public class TitleBodyModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public TitleBodyModel() { Title = Body = ""; }

    public TitleBodyModel(string t, string b) { this.Title = t; this.Body = b; }
}
```

In the main View:

```
@Html.Partial("_TitleBody" , new XXX.Models.TitleBodyModel("title", "body" ))
```

Then in a partial view:

```
@model XXX.Models.TitleBodyModel


<div class="bl_item">
    <div class="bl_title">@Model.Title</div>

    <div class="bl_body">@Model.Body</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this can be a solution:

```
public ActionResult Index(string mainnav, string subnav)
{
   return View(mainnav | subnav);
}
```

In the Html View you can use View
and after

```
<%=Model %>
```

Comment: ?  Doesn't compile... | operator doesn't apply to strings

Comment: No sorry, miss understanding, i mean that you can use one of the two string... the choice is made by yourself analizing what you want to do (sorry, bad english, i'm italian).

Comment: He want's to pass *both* strings to the view *at the same time*, rendering your solution insufficient.