# Pass value in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass data of method to another method. Can you help me please?

Here is my code: `return View(model);` model should be pass `public ActionResult ShowData(Student model)` method.

```
public ActionResult ShowData(int? ID)
{
    var model = new StudentModel
    {
         StudentData = stdDef
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowData(Student model) {
```

Comment: This link may be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816869/mvc-pass-parameter-to-view

Comment: Your code snippet seems to be incomplete. Can you add the missing rest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we pass model as a parameter in RedirectToAction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505674/can-we-pass-model-as-a-parameter-in-redirecttoaction)

Comment: @Hina Khuman  My question isnot pass in redirect to action.I want to pass defined model to HttpPOST public ActionResult ShowData(Student model

Comment: @harry: It seems unclear to me! What you want to exactly? why do you want that?

Comment: @harry is the answer I  provided adequate?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done.  Please pay attention to my comments in the code:

Controller/Model:

```
public class StudentModel
{
    public string StudentData { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public string PassDataToMe(StudentModel model)
    {
        return model.StudentData;//no view defined
    }

    public ActionResult ShowData(int? ID)
    {
        var stdDef = "stdDef";
        var model = new StudentModel
        {
            StudentData = stdDef
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    //!changed this to studentmodel
    public ActionResult ShowData(StudentModel model)
    {
        //this is how you pass limited bytes of data that are not encrypted
        return RedirectToAction("PassDataToMe", model);   
    }
```

View:

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.StudentModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ShowData</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(r => r.StudentData);
            @Html.TextBoxFor(r=>r.StudentData);
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```