# Parameter Passing in HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 levels of EF Core scaffolds:

1. for shipment headers and
2. for shipment detail lines.

From the header's `./Index` page, there's a link that passes the shipment header's ID so that only that shipment's lines are displayed on its `./Index` page.  However, I can't get the shipment header's ID to pass in the link for the line's `./Create` page, so the result is a constraint error when the line is saved.

When I attempt to use `{id:int}` in the asp-route-id for the create URL, it either only sends a translation of that text or reverts back to the URL for the ./Index.

```
@page  "{id:int}"

<a asp-page="./Create/" asp-route-id="{id:int}">Create New</a>
```

Does anyone know how to pass the ID as a parameter to another HTML page?

Comment: Im not quite sure what kind of technologie you use as this unfortunately does not come out of the question.
I would possibly specify the page name like ```@page "/something/{id:int}"```.
Could be that the `/` is missing. Could you specify the technology you use?

However if you are using `.razor` files you need this in the `@code` part like:

```csharp
[Parameter]
public int Id { get; set;}
```
If you are asking stuff, you need to asume that we may not know the context. I hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what kind of technology you use.

I would possibly specify the page name like `@page "/something/{id:int}"`.

Could be that the `/` is missing.

However if you are using `.razor` files you need this in the `@code` part like:

```cs
[Parameter]
public int Id { get; set;}
```

In case it is a `.cshtml` file and using ASP.NET MVC you can see [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-passing-data-from-controller-to-view/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4816966/11932313) how to pass parameters in a different way

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@RouteData.Values["xxx"]` to get data from Route.

```
<a asp-page="./Create/" asp-route-id=@RouteData.Values["id"]>Create New</a>
```